# How to address 50% packet loss in first hop on mtr

Tags: networking

I have run mtr to 8.8.8.8. I have upwards of 50% packet loss on the first hop to 142.254.191.13. These issues began about 24 hours ago and fluctuate frequently. I will have good internet for about 2-5 minutes at a time before returning to horribly slow speeds. It can take upwards of 30 seconds to load a simple webpage.

What does this tell me about where my packets are being lost? Is there an issue with my configuration or is this something that exists on Spectrum's end?

How can I diagnose this further?

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                      WinMTR statistics                                   |
|                       Host              -   %  | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |
|------------------------------------------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|                                    ubnt -    0 |  316 |  316 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|                          142.254.191.13 -   51 |  104 |   51 |    0 |   22 |  117 |   11 |
|      xe-0-0-4.hnllhiku01h.hawaii.rr.com -   50 |  107 |   54 |    0 |   57 |  405 |   29 |
|         agg37.milnhixd01r.hawaii.rr.com -   57 |   98 |   43 |    8 |   22 |   55 |   18 |
|          agg31.lsancarc01r.socal.rr.com -   55 |   99 |   45 |   53 |   68 |  121 |   57 |
|bu-ether16.lsancarc0yw-bcr00.tbone.rr.com -   49 |  108 |   56 |   59 |   75 |  132 |   67 |
|                           74.125.48.188 -   51 |  104 |   51 |   56 |   68 |  102 |   60 |
|                          64.233.174.209 -   47 |  110 |   59 |   60 |   76 |  175 |   63 |
|                         142.250.228.235 -   51 |  104 |   51 |   59 |   74 |  106 |   61 |
|                              dns.google -   50 |  106 |   53 |   58 |   73 |  105 |   68 |
|________________________________________________|______|______|______|______|______|______|
```

When I completely bypass my router and plug directly into the modem, this is what I see:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                      WinMTR statistics                                   |
|                       Host              -   %  | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |
|------------------------------------------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|                          142.254.191.13 -   56 |   18 |    8 |    9 |   18 |   33 |   21 |
|         agg61.hnllhiku01h.hawaii.rr.com -   41 |   22 |   13 |   17 |   48 |  163 |  163 |
|         agg37.milnhixd01r.hawaii.rr.com -   56 |   18 |    8 |    9 |   23 |   49 |   21 |
|          agg31.lsancarc01r.socal.rr.com -   41 |   22 |   13 |   54 |   65 |   94 |   67 |
|bu-ether26.lsancarc0yw-bcr00.tbone.rr.com -   41 |   22 |   13 |   59 |   72 |  100 |   75 |
|                            74.125.49.40 -   41 |   22 |   13 |   57 |   68 |   97 |   70 |
|                           74.125.253.15 -   41 |   22 |   13 |   63 |   74 |  103 |   75 |
|                           216.239.46.97 -   56 |   18 |    8 |   57 |   71 |   97 |   70 |
|                              dns.google -   41 |   22 |   13 |   59 |   70 |   99 |   71 |
|________________________________________________|______|______|______|______|______|______|
```

In my modem logs, I am seeing this nearly every minute.

```
Sat Aug 15 19:19:14 2020    Critical (3)    Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC=08:36:c9:3f:9b:98;CMTS-MAC=00:01:5c:76:6c:59;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.1;
Sat Aug 15 19:10:46 2020    Warning (5) ToD request sent- No Response received;CM-MAC=08:36:c9:3f:9b:98;CMTS-MAC=00:01:5c:76:6c:59;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.1;
Sat Aug 15 19:10:30 2020    Critical (3)    Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC=08:36:c9:3f:9b:98;CMTS-MAC=00:01:5c:76:6c:59;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.1;
Sat Aug 15 19:10:13 2020    Warning (5) ToD request sent- No Response received;CM-MAC=08:36:c9:3f:9b:98;CMTS-MAC=00:01:5c:76:6c:59;CM-QOS=1.1;CM-VER=3.1;
```

Comment: Is it always approx 50%, or is it varying greatly?

Comment: Since i have been checking in the last 2 hours, it has always been ~50%.

Comment: Speak to your ISP.